# CSS Bootstrap:When I upload the image from the ios device, object-fit: cover; doesn't work in android and pc devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, vue.js

I am using vue-bootstrap.
I want to effect object-fit: cover to the image.

I uploaded the image from my ios device(iphone X), then when I check the android device and the desktop web browser(chrome), the aspect ratio is not fixed and the style is not working properly.

> In the android device and the pc, the image is stretched sideways.

I also checked other ios devicies like iphone 7, the style was perfect.

Now the image size is correct.

How can I fix this issue?
I searched the web pages, and this problem might be caused by exif information rather than the css style.

template file

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-container class=" mx-auto">
            <b-row class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <b-col cols="5">
                    <div class="image-area mx-auto" v-for="(item, index) in imageData" v-bind:key="index">
                        <img :src="item" alt="" class="picture">
                    </div>
                </b-col>
                <b-col cols="7" vertical-align="center">
                     <div  class="upload">
                             <input type="file"  name="imageSample" @change="uploadStorefront" id="file" accept="image/png,image/jpeg">
                                <label for="file">
                                    Upload
                                </label>
                        </div>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
        </b-container>
    </div>
</template>
```

css

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>

.picture-size {
    margin-top: 9rem;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.image-area {
    margin-left: 12rem;
}

.picture {
    height: 228px;
    width: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
    //0.57142857
}

input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

.upload {
    margin-top: 74px;
    margin-left: 13rem;
    border-radius: 27px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(85deg, #aa233a, #aa233a, 60%, #472958);
    border: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
}


</style>
```

Comment: Your `v-for` loop is on the wrapper `div.image-area`, meaning every item gets its own centered wrapper. Also, the margin-left of the image area is overwritten by the mx-auto utility class. Is this intended, or did you mean for it to loop through the `<img>` tags?

Things like that could also prevent images from showing up correctly.

Comment: I tried uploading the picture from the PC, then object-fit style worked. But if I upload from my ios device, it doesn't work properly. Also, I removed class="image-area mx-auto".

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what doesn’t work properly? Different devices have different aspect ratios so you’ll se more or less of an img on object-fit on different devices.

Comment: I edited my question, the image is stretched sideways.